# Nvida drivers not loading on boot (Intel HD used for Displays)

Tags: drivers, server, 16.04, nvidia, graphics

I am using a GTX 1070 in Ubuntu 16.04. I installed the 367.57 Drivers via the run file, downloaded directly from nvidia.com. Using the nvidia-370 package from apt is not working for me (drivers do not load)

My displays are connected to my Intel HD4600 integrated Graphics, because I need the GTX 1070 only for computational purposes.

After a reboot the drivers are not loaded and I have to reinstall them (don't know how to load them manually). Then everything works till the next reboot.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't work like that. You shouldn't expect the Nvidia card to work without monitors attached. The Nvidia driver for Linux cannot make use of the integrated ports. Whether or not it does that in Windows is irrelevant.

Comment: But it works after installing the drivers (On Ubuntu !!).  I'm currently using the nvidia card for computations without any monitors.... only after reboot the drivers are not loaded. That means it should be possible, right?